# how to make a terminal app that codes, and decodes a string with 2 parameters, the abc, and the coderkey abc

Tags: c++

It gives an error (segmentation fault, core dumped),
unless i feed it with a string like this: abcdefghijk.
I have to start with an A and continue with the alphabeth. the lenght is not matters.
I just started c++ and i don't even know what segmentation fault(core dumped) means.
If you have any solutions please let me know. :3

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void code(string word)
{
    char abc[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char sabc[] = {'z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y'};
    int ilist[word.size()];
    char elist[word.size()];
    for(int iw = 0; iw < word.size(); iw++)
    {
        for (int ic = 0; ic < 26; ic++)
        {
            if(word[iw] == abc[ic])
            {
                ilist[ic] = iw;
            }else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }  
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        elist[i] = sabc[ilist[i]];
    }
    for(int f = 0; f < word.size(); f++)
    {
       cout << elist[f];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void decode(string word)
{
    string sabc = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    string abc = {'z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y'};
    int ilist[word.size()];
    char elist[word.size()];
    for(int iw = 0; iw < word.size(); iw++)
    {
        for (int ic = 0; ic < 26; ic++)
        {
            if(word[iw] == abc[ic])
            {
                ilist[ic] = iw;
            }else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }  
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
        elist[i] = sabc[ilist[i]];
    }
    for(int f = 0; f < word.size(); f++)
    {
        cout << elist[f];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    int todo;
    string todowith;
    cout << "P||1 = CODE\nP||2 = DECODE\nP||WHAT TO DO?: ";
    cin >> todo;
    if(todo == 1)
    {
        cout << "P||WHAT TO CODE?: ";
        cin >> todowith;
        code(todowith);
    }else if(todo == 2)
    {
        cout << "P||WHAT TO DECODE?: ";
        cin >> todowith;
        decode(todowith);
    }else
    {
        cout << "P||THERE IS NO OPTION: " << todo << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

"""

Comment: `int ilist[word.size()];` and so are VLAs (variable length arrays) which are NOT part of the C++ standard

Answer (score 0):

`ilist[ic] = iw;`
Ic goes to 25, but there's no guantee that ilist -length=word.size- has 26 elements. So it goes out of bounds, which gives the exception you see.

Try to use std::vector instead of VLAs by the way.

Comment: What is a VLA? And why shouldn't i use them?

Comment: @karolydrienko variable length array. See my comment at the question. These are a compiler specific extention, but not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: my dear friend. i tried overwriting the  26 with 25, but it gave me the same error. or am i missunderstood your explanation, and did something stupid agan?

Comment: @karolydrienko `int ilist[word.size()];` then `for (int ic = 0; ic < 26; ic++) ... ilist[ic] = iw;` will give a problem. You cannot do `ilist[n]` for any n>=word.size